# Store date in DD-MMM-YYYY format

Tags: date, batch-file

I am trying to get today's date in `DD-MMM-YYYY` format (for example, 12-JUN-2015) so that I can download a file from an FTP server that will be created daily.

i m using

```
@echo off
set month-num=%date:~3,2%
IF "%month-num:~0,1%"=="0" SET month-num=%month-num:~1%
FOR /f "tokens=%month-num%" %%a in ("jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec") do set mo-name=%%a
echo %mo-name%
```

it is giving syntax error

I would appreciate any advice, as I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Fine, nice to know it!

Comment: Which OS are you working on? Is it windows where you are gona have the batch files?

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799236/388389

Comment: i m using  @echo off
set month-num=%date:~3,2%
IF "%month-num:~0,1%"=="0" SET month-num=%month-num:~1%
FOR /f "tokens=%month-num%" %%a in ("jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec") do set mo-name=%%a
echo %mo-name%   it is giving syntax error please help

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you are using; code is not properly displayed in comments.

Comment: hi..there is no scrip related to 12-JUN-2015..if you please give me ...

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please edit your question to include the code you have tried and we will tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: The down mods and votes to close are inappropriate for a post that's fixable.  Obviously, OP is a rookie, and could use a bit of friendly guidance.  He posted his code in a comment, which was a rookie mistake; yet instead of anyone helping him by editing his question and making it useful, several people continued the modding into oblivion.  This is unproductive and contrary to the spirit of S.O.  Have some patience with new users who have demonstrated a willingness to show their effort, please.

Comment: @rojo - there were five downvotes on this question before I completely rewrote it to prevent further downvotes. My first comment was so that he wouldn't make the same mistake in the future, and my second was a reaction to "please give me the script," again, to prevent future mistakes of this nature.

Answer (score 3):

Ganesh, your use of a `for /f` loop to convert the numeric month to its abbreviation is pretty clever.  I think part of your problem is that whoever originally wrote the code you're using wrote it for *their* locale, not yours.  `%date%` looks different to the original author than it looks to you.

The format of `%date%` is unpredictable (well, without complicated registry queries and conversions anyway).  To obtain datetime in a locale agnostic way, it's easier to use `wmic os get localdatetime`.

Try this:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list ^| find "="') do set "%%I"
set "YYYY=%localdatetime:~0,4%"
set /a "MM=1%localdatetime:~4,2% - 100"
set "DD=%localdatetime:~6,2%"
for /f "tokens=%MM%" %%I in ("JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC") do set "month=%%I"

echo %DD%-%month%-%YYYY%
```

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Normally reports will be asked for previous month. So to get previous month, here is a little modification:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list ^| find "="') do set "%%I"
set "YYYY=%localdatetime:~0,4%"
set /a "MM=1%localdatetime:~4,2% - 101"
set "DD=%localdatetime:~6,2%"
for /f "tokens=%MM%" %%I in ("JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC") do set "month=%%I"

echo %month%-%YYYY%
```

Now passing this mmm-yyyy to your EXE will make it run for that month.

Comment: This is confusing why post a solution for a different question.  I missed that this is actually returning the PREVIOUS month.  Look at Rojos solution for current month as per the question.